# VCR+rspec metadata: how to use inferred cassette name like use_vcr_cassette

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, convention, vcr

The `VCR` testing gem provides a macro called `use_vcr_cassette` that has a handy convention to [infer the cassette name](https://www.relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/docs/test-frameworks/usage-with-rspec-macro) based on the example name. Since the `use_vcr_cassette` macro is deprecated in the latest versions of VCR in favor of rspec metadata (i.e. `:vcr`), is there still any way to automatically pick up the cassette name without having to go specify it in every spec?

(BTW I'm using this with a Rails application.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Configuring RSpec to enable `configure_rspec_metadata!` will enable [automatic cassette naming](https://www.relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/2-0-0/docs/test-frameworks/usage-with-rspec-metadata).

```
require 'vcr'

VCR.configure do |c|
  c.cassette_library_dir = 'spec/cassettes'
  c.hook_into :fakeweb
  c.configure_rspec_metadata!
end

RSpec.configure do |c|
  # so we can use :vcr rather than :vcr => true;
  # in RSpec 3 this will no longer be necessary.
  c.treat_symbols_as_metadata_keys_with_true_values = true
end
```